# Talend: Using tfilelist to access files from a shared network path

Tags: talend

I have a Talend job that searches a directory and then uploads it to our database.
It's something like this: dbconnection>twaitforfile>tfilelist>fileschema>tmap>db
I have a subjobok that then commits the data into the table iterates through the directory and movies files to another folder.

Recently I was instructed to change the directory to a shared network path using the same components as before (I originally thought of changing components to tftpfilelist, etc.)

My question being how to direct it to the shared network path. I was able to get it to go through using double \ but it won't read any of the new files arriving.
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the path is accessible?  Have you tried connecting thought different means?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The path is accessible it's something along the lines of \\IP address\ Folder\other folder\

Comment: can you access the path outside of talend?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you use `tWaitForFile` on the local filesystem Talend/Java will hook somehow into the folder and get a message if a new file is being put into it.

Now, since you are on a network drive first of all this is out of reach of the component. Second, the OS behind the network drive could be different.

I understand your job is running all the time, listening. You could change the behaviour to putting a `tLoop` first which would check the file system for new files and then proceed. There must be some delta check in how the new files get recognized.